# Send IoT Hub Cloud-to-Device message from Stream Analytics Output (Using Event Hub endpoint)

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

We use Stream Analytics successfully for ingesting event messages sent from IoT Hub devices. Stream Analytics supports IoT Hub as Input stream out of the box.
But now we have a requirement to send the Stream Analytics Output result to an IoT Hub Device. We are able to setup an Event Hub connection to IoT Hub as the Output sink for Stream Analytics, but we get an error event raised: 
`Message: Access to the Event Hub has been denied. The token may have an invalid signature.`

Which raises the question; is it at all possible to send IoT Hub Cloud-to-Device messages from an Stream Analytics Output sink?

Answer (score 1):

- Sending an IoT Hub C2D Message (non-telemetry path) from the Stream Analytics job can be done indirectly via the Service Bus entity (Queue/Topic), see the following screen snippet:

[ASA-to-Device Messaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvctE.png)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that solution requires Azure Functions to do the C2D routing. For our scenario we do not want to depend on any custom code/implementation.

Comment: There is no direct way for sending a C2D message from the ASA to the IoT Hub. The minimum plumbing is to use a custom precompile Azure Function (bridge) which it will allow to make all integration by declarative way.

Comment: Thanks again Roman. Can you please clarify why there is no direct way? ASA is able to output to an Event Hub endpoint​, so I was thinking why not to the devicebound endpoint in IoT C2D? If both ends talk AMQP, what is stopping that scenario exactly?

Comment: Azure IoT Hub is a bidirectional GATEWAY between the Devices and Azure Cloud Solution. Its service-facing input endpoints are not compatible either with Azure Event Hub or Azure Service Bus entities.