# Azure IoT hub cloud to device message using Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am sending data through the path as below.

> Android -> IoT Hub -> Stream Analytics -> SQL

I am calling machine learning function at the query of Stream Analytics. Now, I want to return the result of machine learning to the Android device. For receiving cloud-to-device message at Android device, I have done and tested with Device Explorer. I am looking at official tutorials, [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d) but still no clue on how to send cloud to device message using the Stream Analytics. [He](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249691/send-iot-hub-cloud-to-device-message-from-stream-analytics-output-using-event-h) said using the service bus and function app but did not give the details. I am new to Azure. Hoping someone will give me some guidance or any link so I can understand more on how to implement it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an **Azure Function (Preview)** to output an ASA job for sending a *cloud-to-device message* via the Azure IoT Hub service-facing endpoint.

The following is an example of this function.

run.csx:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// create proxy
static Microsoft.Azure.Devices.ServiceClient client = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myIoTHub"]);

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(string input, HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"ASA Job: {input}");

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(input, new[] { new { xyz = "", IoTHub = new { ConnectionDeviceId = ""}}});

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[0]?.IoTHub?.ConnectionDeviceId))
    {
        string deviceId = data[0].IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId;
        log.Info($"Device: {deviceId}");

        // cloud-to-device message 
        var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { temp = 20.5 });
        var c2dmsg = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg));

       // send AMQP message
       await client.SendAsync(deviceId, c2dmsg);
    }

   return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "input",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

project.json:

```
{
   "frameworks": {
   "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.Devices": "1.3.2"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

**Appendix A**

For the test purpose, make the following steps:

1. Add the setting *myIoTHub* in your Azure Function App for your
   connection string to the Azure IoT Hub.
2. Create HttpTrigger function, let call it as *HttpASA_1*
3. Update run.csx, function.json and project.json files with the above contents
4. Use the following sample for *Test* Request Body:

[
      {
    "time": "2017-11-26T12:52:23.4292501Z",
    "counter": 57,
    "windSpeed": 8.7358,
    "temperature": 16.63,
    "humidity": 79.42,
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2017-11-26T12:52:21.3568252Z",
    "PartitionId": 2,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2017-11-26T12:52:22.435Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": null,
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "**Device1**",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636189812948967054",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2017-11-26T12:52:21.562Z",
      "StreamId": null
    }
  }
]

Change the value *Device1* for your actually deviceId.

5. Now, the AF is ready to test it. Press the button *Run* to run the sample and look at the Logs progress.
6. You should see a C2D Message sent by AF on your device, or you can download a small tester [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester) to simulate your MQTT Devices. The following screen snippet shows this tester:

[image: tester]

7. Now, in this step we can go to the ASA job for invoking this HttpASA_1 function. Note, that the ASA job invoking only the HttpTrigger function. The following screen snippet shows adding an output for our Azure Function:

[image: outputs]

You should see this function in the combobox when you selected your subscription in the *Import option* combobox. Once you done, press the *Save* button and watch the notification message on the screen. The ASA will send a validation message to your AF and its response status should be 20x code.

8. Finally, you can go to the *Query* to generate an output for your AF. The following screen shows a simple output for all telemetry data to the AF:

[image: sql]

Note, the *inpsim* is my iothub input.

The ASA outputs payload for HttpTrigger Function in the following format, see my example:

```
[
  {
    "time": "2017-11-26T12:52:23.4292501Z",
    "counter": 57,
    "windSpeed": 8.7358,
    "temperature": 16.63,
    "humidity": 79.42,

    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2017-11-26T12:52:21.3568252Z",
    "PartitionId": 2,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2017-11-26T12:52:22.435Z",
    "IoTHub": {
      "MessageId": null,
      "CorrelationId": null,
      "ConnectionDeviceId": "Device1",
      "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636189812948967054",
      "EnqueuedTime": "2017-11-26T12:52:21.562Z",
      "StreamId": null
    }
  }
]
```

Note, that my telemetry data (*) are *counter*, *temperature*, *humidity* and timestamp *time*, so the other properties are created implicitly by ASA job. Based on the query, you can create any business properties for C2D message.

Comment: The "myIoTHub" has to changed with my IoT hub name? How to set input for this azure app in stream analytics?

Comment: see the Appendix A in my answer

Comment: I have the error when running. 

2017-11-29T11:06:46.314 Device: Android

2017-11-29T11:06:46.330 Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. f-HttpTriggerCSharp1__-1410912764: The type initializer for 'Submission#0' threw an exception. Microsoft.Azure.Devices: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: iotHubConnectionString.

Comment: Did you follow the about steps? Which step failed, the Step 5.?

Comment: Yes, I failed at step 5. Previously, I miss the step 1. Now, I added the connection string to Application Setting->Connection String. The connection string is the connection of iothubowner or device? I tried both but still facing the same error.

Comment: Oic. It should be added to Application Settings. I will continue to the next step.

Comment: It works. I really appreciate your effort in explaining step by step.